# sec:authorize not working as expected using Thymeleaf in a Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am trying to add a link to a new row in a table , this link should only be accessible to the ADMIN Role.

spring boot : 1.4.0.RELEASE 
& thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version : 2.1.2.RELEASE

```
 <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
 </sec:authorize>
```

Namespaces used are :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```

WebSecurityConfigAdapter:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/systemuser/*").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        //.antMatchers("/*").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        //.antMatchers("/ui/report/win").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        //.antMatchers("/userError").access("hasRole('ROLE_ERROR')")
        .antMatchers("/swagger*/**", "/about", "/").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
;
http.csrf().disable();
```

But with this code , even users without ADMIN privileges are able to view the row of the table .

Can someone please help me with the way forward?

Comment: Are you sure to add the right roles to the user during you implementation of  ( AuthenticationProvider.authenticate(...) ?

Comment: Yes,I am sure about it

Comment: You can try removing the call to`.access()` and use the `hasRole("ADMIN")` method directly.  You shouldn't need the `ROLE_` prefix anymore either.

Comment: He needs to show/hide an html element, even removeing the access() he still has the same necessity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should works.. 
I'm pretty sure that you are adding the ROLE_ADMIN also to this user. 
Try to debug the controller that renders the jsp where you are using the tag, tehn obtain your principle object from the Authentication

```
  authentication.getPrincipal()
```

and traverse the object until you don t find the GrantedAuthority, there check if the user has the ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: It seems like version conflict between multiple dependencies and thats why it wasn't working. It works fine now thanks.